# PDO Delete query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have this code that don't want work, and i can't understand why...

```
$DeleteT=$con->prepare("DELETE Examples FROM USERS WHERE Email=:Email AND Pass=:Pass");
$DeleteT->bindParam(':Pass', $Pass);
$DeleteT->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
$DeleteT->execute(array(
      ':Email' => $Email,
      ':Pass' => $Pass,
));
```

I have already tried to search for example of delete query, but i still can't understand why, my value don't want to be delete from database, i have also check if the name of the table and the name of the database match, and they do.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You're binding first, then executing with the same parameters again?

Comment: You either bind the parameters OR execute the array, not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently binding the variables *twice* - once through `bindParam()`, then **once again** as the argument to `execute()`. You need to bind the variable once, either by `bindParam()` or by `execute()`, but not both at the same time.

Also, the syntax for deleting is `DELETE FROM...`, not `DELETE column FROM...`.

So it'll either look like this, binding them through `execute()`

```
$DeleteT = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM USERS WHERE Email=:Email AND Pass=:Pass");
$DeleteT->execute(array(
  ':Email' => $Email,
  ':Pass' => $Pass
));
```

or, if you want to use `bindParam()`...

```
$DeleteT = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM USERS WHERE Email=:Email AND Pass=:Pass");
$DeleteT->bindParam(':Pass', $Pass);
$DeleteT->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
$DeleteT->execute();
```

Either is fine for this purpose, choose which one you like most. `PDOStatement::bindParam()` has additional options should you need it (there's additional information on that in the [documentation](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam) linked below), but for the purpose of binding two strings, either way is applicable.

---

**Update:**
As per the comments, you wish to just empty out the `Examples` column. This means that you want to `UPDATE` the row, not `DELETE` it. The example below would set the `Example` column to an empty string (assuming that it's a text or varchar column, and accept strings). If you wish to set it to `NULL` or another value, modify it as such.

```
$DeleteT = $con->prepare("UPDATE USERS SET Examples=:example WHERE Email=:Email AND Pass=:Pass");
$DeleteT->execute(array(
  ':example' => '', 
  ':Email' => $Email,
  ':Pass' => $Pass
));
```

---

> **SECURITY NOTE**:
>   You should **NEVER** store passwords in plain-text, or by using poor methods of hashing (such as `md5()`, `sha1()`, etc). **It's simply not secure!** PHP has built-in functions which you should use to handle storing of passwords, see the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which is a lot more secure!

- [PHP.net on `PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam)
- [PHP.net on `PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute)
- [MySQL documentation on `DELETE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)

Comment: I delete the bindParam, but it still don't work, anyway thank you, for your time!

Comment: Then you'll need to figure out if there's any errors coming from MySQL. Set PDO to throw exceptions on errors, by adding `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after creating the PDO connection. Then check your logs (or enable error-reporting if you haven't already).

Comment: @A.Rossi There was also a syntax error in the query, see my updated answer.

Comment: But i want, only delete the Examples, columns, how can i do it?

Comment: What do you mean by delete that column? Do you want to set it to `NULL`, set to an empty string, or what? `DELETE` removes an entire row.

Comment: I want to set empty the Example row, of the USERS table where email=:email and pass=:pass

Comment: See my revised answer about that.That column i's a string, right? And not a number or anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are binding on the wrong variable you need to bind on `$Delete` instead of `$DeleteT`

This is what you need

```
$DeleteT=$con->prepare("DELETE Examples FROM USERS WHERE Email=:Email AND Pass=:Pass")->execute(array(':Email' => $Email,':Pass' => $Pass));
```

> PS : Note the extra `,` on `':Pass' => $Pass,));` remove it. Also don't store password in plain text, use password_hash() and password_verify()

Comment: Sorry i wrongly type the code, but it still don't  work. Anyway tank you for the answer!

Comment: write the correct code then, otherwise we won't knw the issue @A.Rossi

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the delete isn't standard, should be `delete from tableName` ...

```
    $DeleteT=$con->prepare("DELETE FROM USERS WHERE Email=:Email AND Pass=:Pass");
    $DeleteT->execute(array(
      ':Email' => $Email,
      ':Pass' => $Pass
    ));
```